# Sending large data over UDP

Tags: c#, udp, .net-4.5, networkstream

Is there a possible way to send large image file(2 MB) over UDP connection, as UDPClient has limit of 65535 byes?

I tried to send data in chunks with application level synchronisation, but delay overhead is killing the purpose of stream.

I'm sending data in chunks of 50k bytes,

<start>
----part----
----part----
----part----
----part----
<end>

However as sending is done asynchronously, end packet is received before the client receives missing parts of image, and it proceeds with received packets.

Also, the stream needs to be live so the reader cannot have overhead of maintaining chunks in buffer and wait for related part to arrive.

Any suggestions on hoe it should be donw?

Comment: Large ordered packets in a stream pattern sent reliably... You need TCP not UDP IMHO...

Comment: @PhilippeParé I already have tried using TCP, the problem with TCP is it slows down thread (may be due to ack-resend), which reads stream, so just want to make sure if it works properly over UDP.

Comment: I understand you need performance, but UDP requires a bit more work on your part. Besides, TCP should be very comparable in terms of performance... maybe you could look at disabling Nagle's algorithm, or `client.NoDelay = true`

Comment: @PhilippeParé I did use NoDelay parameter, but I'm not aware about "disabling Nagle's algorithm", I'll look for it. Thanks.

By any chance, it there a way I can know maximum parallel streams I can create in .NET?

Comment: What do you mean by "parallel streams"? sockets? as much as the OS can give you...

Comment: I understand that, I can have as many sockets as I want, however, as the output streams are intended for different clients and the share same outgoing interface card(NIC), they will certainly create delay in thread which will ask Sockets to write on those output stream, so is there a way I can minimize that delay?

Comment: You need to create another question for that. But there's no such thing as "Thread delay", the TCP stack will receive the packets and queue them. You thread could only be "delayed" if the write call you make is a "blocking call". For more details, create a new question with relevant code.

Comment: @PhilippeParé Thank you for your suggestions.